# Proving of Formula

Tags: geometry

We all know that whenever we have to get the sum of the interior angles of any n-sided polygon , we generally apply the formula $180(n-2)$ , where 'n = number of sides of the polygon..'

From where did this formula come ?

Comment: There are Many different methods of arriving at this solution. http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/interior%20angle.htm I found this link by highlighting and googling your phrase, "the sum of the interior angles of any n-sided polygon."

Comment: Hint: a polygon can be triangulated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take an internal point of the polygon, take the segments from this point to the vertices, You have $n$ triangles. Now use the fact that the sum of the internal angle of a triangle is $180°$ .....

Answer (score 0):

We know that each exterior angle of an n-sided regular polygon is 360/n . Since interior angle and exterior angles are measured from the same line ,therefore their sum is 180. Each interior angle is 180 - exterior angle, i.e., 180- 360/n = (180n-2)/n and the sum of n such angles is 180n - 2.